# How to turn a list of a list of dictionaries into a dataframe via loop

Tags: python, list, loops, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of a list of dictionaries. I managed to access each list-element within the outer list and convert the dictionary via pandas into a data-frame. I then save the DF and later concat it. That's a perfect result. But I need a loop to do that for big data.

Here is my MWE which works fine in principle.

```py
import pandas as pd

mwe = [
    [{"name": "Norway", "population": 5223256, "area": 323802.0, "gini": 25.8}],
    [{"name": "Switzerland", "population": 8341600, "area": 41284.0, "gini": 33.7}],
    [{"name": "Australia", "population": 24117360, "area": 7692024.0, "gini": 30.5}],
]

df0 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mwe[0])
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mwe[1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mwe[2])

frames = [df0, df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

It creates a nice table.

[image]

Here is what I tried to create a list of data frames:

```py
for i in range(len(mwe)): 
    frame = pd.DataFrame()
    frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mwe[i])
    frames = []
    frames.append(frame)
```

Addendum: Thanks for all the answers. They are working on my MWE. Which made me notice that there are some strange entries in my dataset. No solution works for my dataset, since I have an inner-list element which contains two dictionaries (due to non unique data retrieval):

....
[{'name': 'United States Minor Outlying Islands', 'population': 300},
  {'name': 'United States of America',
   'population': 323947000,
   'area': 9629091.0,
   'gini': 48.0}],
...

How can I drop the entry for "United States Minor Outlying Islands"?

Comment: So do you want only entries that contain one dictionary? i.e. skip that `United States Minor Outlying Islands` entry entirely?

Comment: Yes please, I would like to drop "US Minor Outlying Island", but keep "US of America"

Comment: Ok, in that case, what dictates that you want to keep `US of America`? Is it that the columns of the latter are valid and the former are not? Are there cases where you might keep both?

Comment: The initial set of countries was given (by web scraping a table). For those I did a json request (at restcountries.eu API). At this point, due to the not unique identifier "United States", it gave me two entries from the database. It's the only instance of such a problem. That's why I guess manual drop would suffice.

Comment: If it's the only instance, a manual drop might suffice. I have edited my answer to give you a few options given the issue you are seeing, and it will at least flatten your data structure so you can use pandas operations to filter your data later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get each dict out of the containing list and just have a `list` of `dict`:

```py
import pandas as pd
mwe = [[{'name': 'Norway', 'population': 5223256, 'area': 323802.0, 'gini': 25.8}],
 [{'name': 'Switzerland',
   'population': 8341600,
   'area': 41284.0,
   'gini': 33.7}],
 [{'name': 'Australia',
   'population': 24117360,
   'area': 7692024.0,
   'gini': 30.5}]]

# use x.pop() so that you aren't carrying around copies of the data
# for a "big data" application
df = pd.DataFrame([x.pop() for x in mwe])


df.head()
        area  gini         name  population
0   323802.0  25.8       Norway     5223256
1    41284.0  33.7  Switzerland     8341600
2  7692024.0  30.5    Australia    24117360
```

By bringing the list comprehension into the dataframe declaration, that list is temporary, and you don't have to worry about the cleanup. `pop` will also consume the dictionaries out of `mwe`, minimizing the amount of copies you are carrying around in memory

As a note, when doing this, `mwe` will then look like:

```py
mwe
[[], [], []]
```

Because the contents of the sub-lists have been popped out

### EDIT: New Question Content

If your data contains duplicates, or at least entries you don't want, and the undesired entries don't have matching columns to the rest of the dataset (which appears to be the case), it becomes a bit trickier to avoid copying data as above:

```py
mwe.append([{'name': 'United States Minor Outlying Islands', 'population': 300}, {'name': 'United States of America', 'population': 323947000, 'area': 9629091.0, 'gini': 48.0}])

key_check = {}.fromkeys(["name", "population", "area", "gini"])

# the easy way but copies data
df = pd.DataFrame([item for item in data
                   for data in mwe 
                   if item.keys()==key_check.keys()])
```

Since you'll still have the data hanging around in `mwe`. It might be better to use a generator

```py
def get_filtered_data(mwe):
    for data in mwe:
        while data: # when data is empty, the while loop will end
            item = data.pop() # still consumes data out of mwe
            if item.keys() == key_check.keys():
                yield item    # will minimize data copying through lazy evaluation

df = pd.DataFrame([x for x in get_filtered_data(mwe)])

        area  gini                      name  population
0   323802.0  25.8                    Norway     5223256
1    41284.0  33.7               Switzerland     8341600
2  7692024.0  30.5                 Australia    24117360
3  9629091.0  48.0  United States of America   323947000
```

Again, this is under the assumption that non-desired entries have invalid columns, which appears to be the case here, specifically. Otherwise, this will at least flatten out the data structure so you can filter it with pandas later

Answer (score 1):

Create and empty DataFrame and loop over the list using `df.append` on each loop:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
    mwe = [[{'name': 'Norway', 'population': 5223256, 'area': 323802.0, 'gini': 25.8}],
     [{'name': 'Switzerland',
       'population': 8341600,
       'area': 41284.0,
       'gini': 33.7}],
     [{'name': 'Australia',
       'population': 24117360,
       'area': 7692024.0,
       'gini': 30.5}]]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame()                                                                                                                                                                   

>>> for country in mwe: 
...     df = df.append(country) 
...

>>> df
            area  gini         name  population
    0   323802.0  25.8       Norway     5223256
    0    41284.0  33.7  Switzerland     8341600
    0  7692024.0  30.5    Australia    24117360
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name', 'population', 'area', 'gini'])
for i in range(len(mwe)):
    df.loc[i] = list(mwe[i][0].values())
```

**Output** :

```
          name       pop       area  gini
0       Norway   5223256   323802.0  25.8
1  Switzerland   8341600    41284.0  33.7
2    Australia  24117360  7692024.0  30.5
```